# Unityで広告表示をしたかっただけなのに、

Tags: java, android, unity3d

今までbuild出来ていたのが、build&runを広告表示させるために1度選択した後は、buildもbuild&runも出来なくなりました。

設定場所も指定できなくなりました。build&runを1度選択した後は。今までbuild出来ていたのに。

buildが出来なくなったので、エラーメッセージまで出てこなくなり、ここに具体的に掲載するのは難しいですが、

確か、Javaのエラーとandroidの設定環境のエラーが出ていたと思います。

しかし、preferenceのxternaltoolを何度チェックしても黄色いエラーの箇所はありません。

健在です。

私のどこが悪いのでしょう。。

広告も表示されないし、こんなに広告を表示させる作業は、buildが出来なくなるとか何かと敷居が高い作業だったのでしょうか？。

寝込んでしまいたくなるくらい頭を抱えながら、でも、まだあきらめずに向き合っています。せっかく、ここまで作ったので。

========================================================

追加のこの記事に対する情報
　　　↓
https://freesworder.net/unity-admob-banner/
のサイトを参考にしながら、やりました。

問題なくエラー表示が途中されることなく出来ていると思ったのですが、最後にbuild&Runでくじけました。
広告は勿論表示されないですし、buildingもbuild&Runも出来なくなりました(´；ω；`)ｳｩｩ。
大変困っています。
どうかお力をお貸しくださいm(__)m。

Comment: お困りのようですね。広告表示をさせるために、具体的にどういった作業を行ったのかも書いていただけると良さそうだなと思いました。質問文下の「編集」から追記できますので、お試しください。

Comment: 掲示板サイトに愚痴をこぼしてもあなたのソースコードは直りませんので、成功していた時点のソースコードをソースコード管理ツールから取り出してそこから試してみましょう。うまくったら１つづつやってみるとよさそう。　真面目に Q&A する気があるなら「やったこと」「期待していること」「具体的に今どうなっているか」を全部書き出して元質問を編集してください。読者はエスパーぢゃないので今のこの質問文からは何もわかりません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

やってみます。

〉成功していた時点のソースコードをソースコード管理ツールから取り出してそこから試してみましょう。

ソースコードは管理ツールはどこにあるのでしょう？。

全くの初心者で自分が何をしていたか説明が上手く出来ません(´；ω；`)ｳｩｩ。

やりたいことを検索かけて、検索結果を基に真似ることは出来ても、それが、何している処理か分からないことが多々あります。

Comment: そういうコメントが出るということは、ソースコード管理ツールを知らない、ないしは、使っていないんでしょうね。それならばご愁傷さまです、うまく動いていた時点に戻すのは手作業ってことになります。今後はぜひ最初から導入してみてください。今なら git がデファクトスタンダードになっちゃっていますが、オイラのお気に入りは hg です。

Comment: 意味が良く分かりません。hgというソースコード管理ツールがあるのでそれを使うとうまく動いていた時点に戻せるから、今はもう手遅れだけど今度から使った方が良いという事でしょうか？。そのhgというソースコード管理ツールは、どこのサイトに行けば手に入るのでしょうか？。

Comment: 今はもう手遅れだけど今度から、に Yes っす。で、今はデファクトスタンダードの git を使ってみるのがいいでしょう。 git は初期学習コストが若干かなり高いのがアレっすけど。検索すれば一発でヒットしますし、あなたの検索の練習を兼ねて自分で探してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かります。